# PHPWord - open_basedir restriction in effect. File is not within the allowed path(s)

Tags: php, apache2, php.ini, phpword

Пытаюсь использовать данную библиотеку в проекте.Столкнулся с проблемой :

```
PHP Warning:  is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp/PHPWordWriter_5bda41ea880b51.91274208/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/admin/web/myhost.com/public_html:/home/admin/tmp) in /home/admin/web/myhost.com/public_html/vendor/phpoffice/phpword/src/PhpWord/Writer/AbstractWriter.php on line 200

PHP Warning:  mkdir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp/PHPWordWriter_5bda41ea880b51.91274208/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/admin/web/myhost.com/public_html:/home/admin/tmp) in /home/admin/web/myhost.com/public_html/vendor/phpoffice/phpword/src/PhpWord/Writer/AbstractWriter.php on line 201
PHP Warning:  is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp/PHPWordWriter_5bda41ea880b51.91274208/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/admin/web/myhost.com/public_html:/home/admin/tmp) in /home/admin/web/myhost.com/public_html/vendor/phpoffice/phpword/src/PhpWord/Writer/AbstractWriter.php on line 259
PHP Warning:  is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp/PHPWordWriter_5bda41ea8b7220.84671578/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/admin/web/myhost.com/public_html:/home/admin/tmp) in /home/admin/web/myhost.com/public_html/vendor/phpoffice/phpword/src/PhpWord/Writer/AbstractWriter.php on line 200
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp/PHPWordWriter_5bda41ea8b7220.84671578/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/admin/web/myhost.com/public_html:/home/admin/tmp) in /home/admin/web/myhost.com/public_html/vendor/phpoffice/phpword/src/PhpWord/Writer/AbstractWriter.php on line 201
PHP Warning:  file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp/557045771748010340.tmp) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/admin/web/myhost.com/public_html:/home/admin/tmp) in /home/admin/web/myhost.com/public_html/vendor/phpoffice/phpword/src/PhpWord/Writer/AbstractWriter.php on line 276
PHP Warning:  ZipArchive::open(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp/557045771748010340.tmp) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/admin/web/myhost.com/public_html:/home/admin/tmp) in /home/admin/web/myhost.com/public_html/vendor/phpoffice/phpword/src/PhpWord/Shared/ZipArchive.php on line 135
PHP Warning:  ZipArchive::open(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp/557045771748010340.tmp) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/admin/web/myhost.com/public_html:/home/admin/tmp) in /home/admin/web/myhost.com/public_html/vendor/phpoffice/phpword/src/PhpWord/Shared/ZipArchive.php on line 135
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: Could not open '/tmp/557045771748010340.tmp' for writing. in /home/admin/web/myhost.com/public_html/vendor/phpoffice/phpword/src/PhpWord/Writer/AbstractWriter.php:287\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/admin/web/myhost.com/public_html/vendor/phpoffice/phpword/src/PhpWord/Writer/Word2007.php(99): PhpOffice\\PhpWord\\Writer\\AbstractWriter->getZipArchive('/tmp/5570457717...')\n#1 /home/admin/web/myhost.com/public_html/tst.php(47): 
PhpOffice\\PhpWord\\Writer\\Word2007->save('/tmp/5570457717...')\n#2 /home/admin/web/myhost.com/public_html/tst.php(52): SaveViaTempFile(Object(PhpOffice\\PhpWord\\Writer\\Word2007))\n#3 {main}\n  thrown in /home/admin/web/myhost.com/public_html/vendor/phpoffice/phpword/src/PhpWord/Writer/AbstractWriter.php on line 287
```

в php.ini директива  имеет следующий вид - open_basedir=/tmp/:/home/admin/tmp/
Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема ?

Comment: Скорее всего смотрите не тот конфиг. Разместите `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` и смотрите фактическое значение. Заодно увидите `Loaded Configuration File`. И вот еще: В Windows разделяйте директории точкой с запятой. На всех остальных системах, разделяйте директории двоеточием.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно добавить директорию для временно созданного файла.

Можно после инициализации PHPWord добавить следующую строку:

```php
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setTempDir('  здесь абсолютный путь до директории temp  ');
```

Права у неё должны быть 777.

Comment: не факт. "PHP Warning:  is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect"

Comment: Конечно, не факт) Но я написал, что у меня сработало. Я просто указал путь именно в директорию самого сайта, а PHPWord лезет вообще за пределы этой директории (вообще в корень сервера!), а ему туда вообще то запрещено лезть, так что получается, что вот это факты, а моё решение это гипотеза. У человека может быть ещё что-то добавлено, но если это просто PHPWord и ничего более, то должно сработать.

Comment: 4 часа потратил, пока Ваш ответ не прочитал, спасибо!